# Unique struct as std::map key not inserting all data

Tags: c++, c++98

I'm trying to fill different maps with "key data", then extract the "key data" as keys into a master map. However; the master map is skipping several unique entries as if there's already an existing key.

Can someone please explain what's happening to the rest of the keys and why they are not inserting into the master map.

This is the struct I'm using as a key to open my master map. (Yes, I know I can use std::tie for the operator overload. My project constraint is c++98 ):

```
struct MyStruct
{
    std::string stringVar;
    unsigned unsigVar;
    float floatVar;

    bool operator<(MyStruct const &rhs) const
    {
        return ((this->unsigVar  > rhs.unsigVar)  ||
                (this->stringVar > rhs.stringVar) ||  
                (this->floatVar  > rhs.floatVar));
    }   
};
```

All "key maps" and master map

```
std::map< std::string, std::vector<std::string> > stringMap;
std::map< std::string, std::vector<unsigned> > unsigMap;
std::map< std::string, std::vector<float> > floatMap;
std::map<MyStruct, int> masterMap;
```

Get key data and push into vectors

```
std::string keys[3] = {"key1", "key2", "key3"};   

std::vector<std::string> strVector;
std::vector<unsigned> unsigVector;
std::vector<float> floatVector;

strVector.push_back("str1");
strVector.push_back("str2");

unsigVector.push_back(10);
unsigVector.push_back(20);

floatVector.push_back(36.0);
floatVector.push_back(37.0);
```

store vector data into "key maps"

```
for (int i=0; i < sizeof(keys)/sizeof(keys[0]); i++)
{
   stringMap.insert( std::make_pair(keys[i], strVector) ); 
   unsigMap.insert( std::make_pair(keys[i], unsigVector) );
   floatMap.insert( std::make_pair(keys[i], floatVector) );
}
```

I then loop through all maps and insert "key data" into master map w/ bogus data

```
// iterators for data maps
std::map< std::string, std::vector<std::string> >::iterator stringIter;
std::map< std::string, std::vector<unsigned> >::iterator unsigIter;
std::map< std::string, std::vector<float> >::iterator floatIter;

// point to first key only
stringIter = stringMap.find(keys[0]);
unsigIter = unsigMap.find(keys[0]);
floatIter = floatMap.find(keys[0]);

// loop through data maps and store into master map
for (int i=0; i < stringIter->second.size(); i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j < unsigIter->second.size(); j++)
    {
        for (int k=0; k < floatIter->second.size(); k++)
        {
            // create struct to easily store into master map
            MyStruct myStruct;
            myStruct.stringVar = stringIter->second[i];
            myStruct.unsigVar = unsigIter->second[j];
            myStruct.floatVar = floatIter->second[k];

            // bogus data
            int data = 3;

            masterMap.insert( std::make_pair(myStruct, data) );

            std::map<MyStruct, int>::iterator masterIter;
            masterIter = masterMap.find(myStruct);

            //make sure all keys & data were inserted
            if (masterIter != masterMap.end())
            {
                std::cout << stringIter->second[i] << "\t"
                          << unsigIter->second[j] << "\t"
                          << floatIter->second[k] << "\t"
                          << masterIter->second <<std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I get:

```
str1    10      36      3
str1    10      37      3
str1    20      37      3
str2    20      37      3
```

This what I expected to get:

```
str1    10      36      3
str1    10      37      3
str1    20      36      3 <--- missing
str1    20      37      3
str2    10      36      3 <--- missing
str2    10      37      3 <--- missing
str2    20      36      3 <--- missing
str2    20      37      3
```

Comment: Did you try debugging your code?

Comment: Are you sure that's a valid _strict weak ordering_? At first glance, it is not. If not, the result is "confusing" the map by violating preconditions, and consequently undefined behaviour.

Comment: Your ordering is broken. For instance, both `{“”, 1, 0} < {“”, 0, 1}` and `{“”, 0, 1} < {””, 1, 0}` are true, but they can’t both be ordered before the other.

Comment: Side note: defining  a proper ordering relation is one of those things that seem much easier than it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible that you intended a comparison somewhat like this:

```
bool operator<(MyStruct const &rhs) const
    {
        return ((unsigVar  < rhs.unsigVar)  ||
                ((unsigVar  == rhs.unsigVar) && 
                (stringVar < rhs.stringVar) ||  
                ((stringVar == rhs.stringVar) && 
                (floatVar  < rhs.floatVar))));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `operator<` isn't fulfilling the *Strict Weak* ordering requirement.

By copying the example implementation for `std::tuple` from [operator==,!=,<,<=,>,>=,<=>(std::tuple)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator_cmp) you could make it something like below.

The implementation pattern doesn't use comparisons for equality to allow for floating point comparisons to appear anywhere. Even if your floating point comparison is at the very end, I've kept the pattern because it's very easy to read and to extend.

It's sorted in descending order as it looks like you want it in the question:

```
bool operator<(MyStruct const &rhs) const {
    if(rhs.unsigVar < unsigVar) return true;
    if(unsigVar < rhs.unsigVar) return false;

    // the "unsigVar"s are equal

    if(rhs.stringVar < stringVar) return true;
    if(stringVar < rhs.stringVar) return false;

    // the "stringVar"s are equal

    // the last one only needs one comparison:
    return rhs.floatVar < floatVar;
}
```

Comment: `<` isn't somehow more magic than `==`. An approach with `==` would yield the same results. However, this _is_ neater to read.

Comment: Yes, I think it makes it extremely simple to extend and rearrange if another sort order is wanted. I haven't compared the assembly with using the more compact ternary operator though. I _expect_ the optimized version to be similar.

Comment: You mean replacing the whole function body with nested conditional operator expressions? The assembly will assuredly be identical yes as the semantics would be identical. Wouldn't be very nice code though.

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison function is incorrect since both these comparisons are true: (1, "b") < (2, "a") and (2, "a") < (1, "b")

- 1 < 2 or "b" < "a"
- 2 < 1 or "a" < "b"

So only one of these keys gets added.

Adding to @steger's answer, you can generate the comparison function using tuples:

```cpp
bool operator<(MyStruct const &rhs) const {
   return std::make_tuple(unsigVar, stringVar, floatVar) < std::make_tuple(
      rhs.unsigVar, rhs.stringVar, rhs.floatVar
   );
}
```

The tuple comparison does a lexical comparison. See point three in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator_cmp

Mind that floating point comparisons are fraught with problems: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/float_comparison.html

Comment: Ah, yes. Missed that constraint.